# Properly securing a ramp

Tags: plywood, toy, joinery

I'm building a 2'x2', 3 floor parking garage for my son.  I've built the core structure out of 1/2" plywood, with dowels supporting it, and 3/16" chalkboard-paper lined plywood glued on top of the plywood on each level (for eventually allowing parking spots to be drawn on and such).  The levels are about 6" apart.

I created two cut-outs for the ramps (ie, cut out about a 8"x3" section, both to leave room for the ramp and to be used for the ramp itself), but I'm working out now how to attach them properly.  What would be the best way in terms of surviving a three or four year old's level of play to attach them while still keeping it looking more or less like a parking garage?

My thoughts were either a hinge (like a door hinge) to attach to the top level and a smaller hinge on the bottom level, or to use a wooden triangle to screw it to.  The angle will be about 30 degrees or so (yes, probably unrealistic, but it seems about to match what other products use).  Is there a better option?  What should I keep in mind while doing this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is technically in scope for WW, but since this is private beta - might as well ask and find out!

Comment: It involves wood and you are working it ... not sure why this would *off-topic*!

Comment: My gut says this is more of a diy.se question, but true, why not take a stab at it.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong.  2 foot by 2 foot?  It's a toy, not diy.  I need to learn to read.

Comment: Yep, intended as a child's toy.

Comment: A picture wold help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to visualize what you are building, but this really sounds like a job for wood glue and some tack brads.  If you're concerned about it working loose over time, you might be able to lay the ramp in a rabbet to increase the glue surface.  One thing to keep in mind is that if you've precalculated your miters, adding the rabbets would change the length and potentially the miter angle by doing it that way.

Comment: I had considered wood glue, but with the relatively small contact surface (not much more than 1/2 in) even with a rabbet (if I understand the term right, that's in this case cutting back some to have two contact surfaces instead of one) made me think glue wouldn't survive.  I can change the position with no problem - the lower position is entirely fliexible - and I probably could make a new ramp from scrap wood instead of using the cutout as a ramp, but too big and it's taking up too much of the total usable surface of the garage.

Comment: I'll try to add a picture when I'm at home.

Comment: A lot of people doubt the holding power of wood glue, but it is surprisingly tenacious.  Since it would be tough to clamp this joint, I'd say some tack brads would help hold it while the glue cured and would also give it some extra structural strength.  A picture would be lovely though!